# MacBook keyboard mod?

Tags: keyboard, hardware-recommendation, macbook-pro, backlight

Is it possible to mod the MacBook keyboard to be backlit? Is there any website or business that can help or would do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always try to find yourself from this FlickR Photos and set it up :)

[Flickr SET](http://www.flickr.com/photos/34268406@N06/sets/72157612409546653/)

[Flickr SET SlideShow](http://www.flickr.com/photos/34268406@N06/sets/72157612409546653/show/)

> How I used the backlighting from a macbook air, to give my white macbook a backlit keyboard.
>
> You couldn't just change the whole keyboard, they're not compatible, but the lighting sheet fits.
>
> Then you have to get nearly 16 volts from a step-up-converter to power the 5 white LEDs and add some electronics for switching it on/off and regulate the keyboard-brightness by the screen-brightness.
>
> If you wanna have a backlit keyboard and think about doing it on your own: forget it and buy a new macbook with integrated backlight.
> You would almost destroy your macbook in the process...

[image]

Comment: In other news… the new Airs do not have backlit anymore. :S

Comment: @Martín nope, saves battery and cables ... and on my opinion, ruins one of the best features of an Apple Laptop.

Comment: wow that really sucks... I love the backlights.

Comment: Okay, I'll wait until I can afford a Pro then...